# Dividing and multiplication math error

Tags: c#, math

I seem to have a problem with my equation, I want to solve a problem like this `Z= A/(C*B)` where `A` is  equal to `F/G(i.e A=F/G)` but it seems I'm getting the same answer when I calculate `A` and `Z` no matter how many times I change the values my program outputs `A` and `Z` to be equal which is mathematically not true because if I say `A=4/2` I get a `2` and `Z = 2/(8*1)` is supposed to be `0.25` think what am I missing out??
my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace trafic_model
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double a = 0, b = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //С1
            a = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) / Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            label3.Text = "C1 = " + a.ToString() + " Мбит/с.";
            //end of c1

            //N1
            z = (a / (Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text)));
            label6.Text = "N1 = " + a.ToString() ;

            //

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
z = (a / (Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text)));
label6.Text = "N1 = " + a.ToString() ;
```

Do you mean that label6 should be `"N1 = " + z.ToString() ;` ?

Answer (score 4):

Just guess you are using the wrong variable, it should be `z` instead of `a` in below line:

```
label6.Text = "N1 = " + z.ToString() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you write a.ToString() into both text boxes and never write z at all..

Change

```
 label6.Text = "N1 = " + a.ToString() ;
```

To

```
label6.Text = "N1 = " + z.ToString() ;
```